# Will long-term participation (posting questions/answers) in a niche tag be considered as a voting fraud?

Tags: discussion

I just wandered around SO and eventually found myself at this [Vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page. After reading it, I have a question that for people who have been participating in a niche tag, like me, will ever be considered as a voting fraud? (likely by the system first)

This is because a tag where I have been participating [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) has only a handful of experts that can properly answer questions in the field. Therefore, whenever someone posts a question in that tag, there is a slightly higher chance than other tags that the people who will come to the rescue (to answer) is often the same people who have answered the user's previous questions before.

That, by itself, can be interpreted almost as repeatedly targeted voting to some specific users even though I genuinely vote the posts because I found them useful almost all the time since the experts answer not only correctly but most of the time they provide great and detailed explanation along with the answer. I never want to vote the post because it is the specific user.

With that context, comes the question. Will I (or other users that have this behavior) ever be considered doing the voting fraud? I think if it does happen, it will be raised by the automatic process of the system before the manual one.

Comment: It really depends on the situation. Generally no.